# How can i set the default file I/O location

Tags: c, file-io, default, fopen

I want to create and write to a file in a specific location on my computer. I have a fairly large project going, so I will just post the part in which I am stuck on.

```
f = fopen(FileName, "w");
```

`FileName` = the variable that contains a file name that I am going to write onto.

The problem is that it's creating and storing this file in the same directory location as my project. I want to store it in a subdirectory called `Individual` that is located in that same directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve in two methods:

**Method 1)** Change directory (**e.g.** use `chdir()` method)

**Method 2)** Add the `path` onto the start of the filename.

Comment: I decided to add it to the start of my FileName variable. Thank you for the help, i should have tried this before asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the same logic in multiple places in your code, write a function named `getFileNameInDirectoryToSave`.

Call the function before `fopen`.

```
void getFileNameInDirectoryToSave(char const* in, char* out)
{
   sprintf(out, "Individual/%s", in);
}

char fileNameToSave[FILESIZE];  // Make FILESIZE large enough.
getFileNameInDirectoryToSave(FileName, fileNameToSave);
fopen(fileNameToSave, "w");
```

---

You can use the same logic if you need that functionality just once.

```
char fileNameToSave[FILESIZE];  // Make FILESIZE large enough.
sprintf(fileNameToSave, "Individual/%s", FileName);
fopen(fileNameToSave, "w");
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `PATH_MAX` for `FILESIZE` but that's just a different brand of foot-gun.